# Can I install CUDA toolkit on Linux Mint 18 (Cinnamon)

Tags: cuda, gpu, linux-mint

Can I install CUDA toolkit on Linux Mint 18.1 Serena (Cinnamon Desktop Environment)? I am asking this because it is not listed on the supported OS list, even though it has the same architecture based on Ubuntu 16.04. My GPU is NVidia GeForce 820M. CPU - i5 5th Gen 5200U. 4GB RAM DDR3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, however the setup process will be a bit more involved. I would recommend installing Ubuntu or otherwise as a dual-boot. But if you must use Mint, the setup process is pretty much the same as Ubuntu. Check out this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/deepdream/comments/3cd1yf/howto_install_on_ubuntulinux_mint_including_cuda/) for some help. I am aware it is "specifically" for Mint 17 but the install process should be identical. ***Be Aware*** anytime you try to install something on a platform it is not "technically" supported, you are likely to run into issues along the way.

Comment: Can you also tell me how much the performance will differ if I use a virtual machine? I am doing a project which involves image processing. The virtual machine would be on Linux itself